# Is it required to show train ticket reservation during visa application to France

Tags: tickets, france, schengen-visas

Hello I'm a student in the UK with Tier-4 visa and I'd like to apply for a Schengen visa of France via TLS Contact.
As title suggests, I'd like to know whether I must present paid train ticket to Paris from London during visa interview?Or is it not compulsory?
I'm asking because those tickets are non-refundable and it will be a huge blow in my pocket if i'm rejected for Schengen.

So far my documents are (for better understanding of my situation and according to as stated in **tlscontact.com**):

- Passport & BRP both originals and copies
- Confirmation of studies from my university (UEA to be specific)
- Bank statements covering last 4    months
- Hotel reservation from booking.com
- A visa to Italy (my only visa from the last 3 yrs which was a single-entry 10    day visa)

So in that case failing to show any proof of transportation will affect it badly or is it not that vital in my case?

Comment: Just buy a Business Premier ticket, which is fully refundable, then cancel it AFTER the visa decision, and (if granted the visa) buy a low-fare ticket

Comment: @Coke 
Thank you!
So, I have to cancel it after the decision have I understood it right?Not just after the interview?

Comment: After the decision, yes, i.e. when, hopefully, the visa is in your passport

Comment: Can you find the info applicable to your situation here? https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.